# how we can dismiss default call sheet(which used to make default call in iOS) and push a controller on complition of dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiapplicationdelegate

want to dismiss defauls call sheet without any tap on view and push controller of dismiss complition

[image: want to dismiss defauls call sheet without any tap on view and push controller of dismiss complition]

I am not clear how I can dismiss this and I am able to find actual name of this controller or etc.

Comment: This dialog is shown by iOS when the app attempts to open a `tel` url. There is nothing you can do with this. It is part of the operating system, not part of your app.  You will get  `willBecomeInactive`/`didBecomeActive` notifications as the dialog is shown and then dismissed

Comment: When you don't want this dialog, just skip calling `"tel://\(phoneNumber)"` instead push the controller which you want to show.